# Understanding the stateful_actor

Tags: c++, c++-actor-framework

I've read the some usage of stateful_actor under [examples/curl/curl_fuse.cpp](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/blob/master/examples/curl/curl_fuse.cpp) and [libcaf_core/test/stateful_actor.cpp](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/blob/master/libcaf_core/test/stateful_actor.cpp). It looks like the `stateful_actor<State>` can bind some states for actor by declaring fields in `State struct`. It is very useful.

Can we declare the states as fields in `class-based actor` to get the same effects? Or there is some special handling in the `stateful_actor` (e.g. thread-safety access) ?

Do the actors in the following example provide the same functionality?

```
/* Class based actor */
struct ClassCounter : caf::event_based_actor
{
    caf::behavior make_behavior() override { 
        return { 
            [=](inc_atom){ i += 1; }
          , [=](ret_atom){ return i; }
        };
    }

    const char* name() const override { return "I am class-based"; }
    int i = 0;
};

/* Stateful actor */
struct CounterState
{
    caf::local_actor* self;
    int i = 0;
    const char* name = "I am stateful";
};

caf::behavior StatefulCounter(caf::stateful_actor<CounterState>* self)
{
    return {
        [=](inc_atom){ self->state.i += 1; }
      , [=](ret_atom){ return self->state.i; }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we declare the states as fields in `class-based actor` to get the same effects? Or there is some special handling in the `stateful_actor` (e.g. thread-safety access) ?

The runtime of CAF assumes actors to be isolated, i.e., only an actor itself is allowed to access its state. Hence, access to the state of an actor is never synchronized. Inter-actor communication uses message passing, thus avoiding race conditions by design.

Stateful actors allow programmers to write less classes (and thus less boilerplate code), but there is also one notable difference between `ClassCounter` and `StatefulCounter`: lifetime of variables. In `ClassCounter`, the member variable `i` lives until the destructor of `ClassCounter` is called. Since actors are reference counted, the destructor runs if no reference to it is left, i.e., no `actor` or `actor_addr` handle to the actor exists. In `StatefulCounter`, the `CounterState` member is constructed if the actor is initialized and destroyed if it terminates.

The state only exists as long as an actor is alive. This is particularly useful for breaking cycles. If you have the two actors `A` and `B`, you have a cycle if `A` holds a reference to `B` via a member variable and vice versa. Using stateful actors instead breaks this cycle. `A` will release its reference to `B` automatically on exit and vice versa.

Comment: So the CounterState's destructor will be called when the actor terminates?

Comment: mm. I think separating the concerns of State and actor behavior is better  for maintenance.

Comment: "So the CounterState's destructor will be called when the actor terminates?" Yes. An actor closes its mailbox and destroys its state when terminating. It will also trigger exit or down messages when necessary. Any further incoming message will be dropped (triggering an error message for sync messages) and linking to a terminated actor will trigger the exit message immediately.